# Need to be able to search through python-packages in VSCode using quick-open

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the django project, I want to able to open package files, search file names and open it using quick-open (Cmd + P). After setting up the virtual environment using `python.Python` in the folder settings, my code navigation from project files to package files are working properly, using Cmd + Click.

However, I am unable to search through the package file-names using Cmd + P. I couldn't find any configuration and keyboard shortcut to do the same. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "_search through the package files_"? Do you mean finding text from specific files?

Comment: @GinoMempin Sorry, I meant search through the package file-names to open the right file. I have made the correction. Thanks.